# Cost breakdown of launch companies

Tags: launch-vehicle, cost, cost-to-orbit, operations

One thing which I recently heard Peter Beck say in an [interview with Tim Dodd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcuOSXjevGs) was that the cost of running a launch company isn't primarily driven by the rocket itself, but the operations required to run it.

I've tried researching what these costs are, and the closest thing I could find is [ULA's chart](https://newspaceglobal.com/launch-vehicle-weight-and-cost-infographic/), but that only breaks down the BOM-related costs.

Ideally, I'd love to hear from those who work/have worked at launch companies and are in a position to give that info publicly. I want to understand what the costs related to launch operations are and why they are the figure they are.

Thanks!

Comment: Very few who are in the know are able to provide the data you want. This is highly competitive data that you want and hence is highly protected with non-disclosure agreements. Tim Dodd did point out some of these costs such as infrastructure costs and turnaround-time (for a reusable rocket). A short turnaround-time means more launches per year, and its the launches that pay the bills. Everything else (cost of building a rocket, cost of building and maintaining infrastructure, etc.: Those are costs. So are other things.

Comment: I stopped watching after a while, so I don't know if he mentioned people costs. Cost-plus launch providers tend to have huge marching armies who spend a lot of their time over the course of a year doing busy work. The launch provider can't lay off those people when the rockets aren't launching and then rehire them later; nobody sane would work for such an employer. (This is yet another area where quick turnaround and a high cadence pays off.) The size of the marching army and the fraction of time the marching army is paid for thumb twiddling are very important.

Comment: I see.. reality is often disappointing, as they say. Thanks for the answer, nevertheless.

Comment: An answer to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65555/does-it-economically-cost-the-same-to-launch-a-satellite-into-leo-and-gto) lists lots of different kinds of costs but lacks a specific breakdown.